# Java - array comparing doesnt terminate when match found?

Tags: java, arrays

Although the recommendations on asking a question did not prohibit this, if I violate any rules by asking specific questions, please let me know.

I am trying to compare the user input to the previous user inputs (1-9) then checking for repeats. However, my program won't stop if it encounters a repeat. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class No_Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean repeat = false;
        do {
            int[] array = new int[9];
            for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a number 1 - 9");
                int num = scan.nextInt();
                array[i] = num;
                for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if(num==array[j])
                        repeat = true;
                }
            }
        }while(!(repeat == true));
        System.out.println("No Duplicates Allowed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop will stop looping when you set `repeat` to true, but the `for` loop will carry on until it's finished, unless you add a `break`.

Comment: btw, you are going to get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here on your last iteration. You can either do `int[] array = new int[10];` or enter your values into array starting with index 0 and incrementing from there

Comment: By the way, `while(!(repeat == true))` should just be written `while (!repeat)` .

Comment: `for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)` this is very wrong. start at 0 and stop before i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't stop when it encounters a repeated element.

I also noticed that you are accessing the array index from `1` not `0`. In Java, array indices start from `0`. So, you should start from `0` and stop before the length of the array. Otherwise, you'll run into `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Here is something you can try:**

```
    boolean repeat = false;

    int[] array = new int[9];

    for(int i=0 ; i<9 && repeat!=true ; i++)//checks for repeated input
    {
      System.out.println("Enter a number 1 - 9");
      int num = scan.nextInt();               
      array[i] = num;

       for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
       {
          if(num==array[j])
          {
             repeat = true;
             break; //breaks out of the loop if encounters a repeated input
           }
        }
    }

if(repeat)
  System.out.println("No Duplicates Allowed!");
```

Comment: the No Duplicates should be no duplicates allowed - i edited my code above

Comment: You can change the display message as you see fit.

Comment: As the code stands, the lase `if` seems superfluous. You only exit the `do` loop if and when `repeat` is true.

Comment: You are right @OleV.V. The 'do while' loop seems redundant too since the outer 'for' loop is handling the repeat check. I'll edit my code. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not so sure about that, but that’s because I’m not sure what the asker really wants to happen after 9 numbers have been entered.

Comment: Yes. But if the 'do while' loop exists, we get stuck in an infinite loop if we enter all unique inputs.

Comment: after 9 the user will have to input a repeat, hence the 1-9, so it will terminate. the only problem with this code is that it terminates immediately after a user input and i cannot find why

Comment: Okay! In our code we are also checking the current element while checking for repeatation. The inner for loop's condition part reads `j<=i`. But it should be `j<i`. Please make this change and see.

Comment: Great! Happy to help! :)